# How to download a text to speech file created in Watson Studio

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson, watson-studio, watson-text-to-speech

I am using Text to Speech in Watson Studio. The output file is '.wav'. Does anyone have got any idea where is the file stored? I want to download it from the IBM cloud to my pc. How should I do this? I have searched entire cloud storage, but couldn't find the speech file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the TTS API from within Watson Studio on Cloud notebooks, the files you write go to the underlying python runtime container's filesystem, which is not persistent.

So, you would have to explicitly copy that file to Cloud Object Storage.
An easy way to do that in WSC is to use the project_lib API (see https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/project-lib-python.html), which will let you create a Data Asset in your project.

You could also use the COS Client API https://ibm.github.io/ibm-cos-sdk-python/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file to copy that file to an arbitrary bucket that you have access to.

Regards,

Philippe Gregoire - IBM Ecosystem Advocacy Group - Data&AI Technical enablement

Comment: Refer this post for project_lib along with download options
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50572405/download-pandas-dataframe-in-watson-studio/50572667#50572667